# Access VBA TransferSpreadsheet count

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` to populate a table. This command is being called using a button on a form. After the transfer is complete I want to tell the user how many records were added. To try and accomplis this I use `db.OpenRecordset("select * from tblImport")` 
then `MsgBox(rs.RecordCount)`
The problem is that the record count is being called before the transfer is complete. Is there anyway to call this synchronously?

Here is the complete code

```
Private Sub cmdVIT_Click()
On Error Resume Next

Dim strPath As String
Dim filePicker As FileDialog
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Set filePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With filePicker
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    .Title = "Select File"

    With .Filters
        .Clear
        .Add "All Files", "*.*"
    End With
    .FilterIndex = 1

    .Show
End With

strPath = filePicker.SelectedItems(1)
Debug.Print strPath
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, TableName:="tblImport", FileName:=strPath, HasFieldNames:=True
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from tblImport")

MsgBox rs.RecordCount & " records"
End Sub
```

Comment: It should work. What is your code, exactly?

Comment: I mean, can you cut and paste the procedure code into your question?

Comment: I just tried running the 'RecordCount' off a separate command button after I did the import and it is still returning a value of only one record. Is there something I am not understanding about recordsets or RecordCount

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an extra line:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from tblImport")
'Populate recordset
rs.MoveLast
MsgBox rs.RecordCount & " records"
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Why do I need that line?

Comment: When you open the recordset at first, it is not populated with all records. Moving last populates the recordset.

Answer (score 2):

You want to display the number of rows contained in `tblImport`.  I don't think you need a recordset to give you that information.  Try one of these ...

```
MsgBox CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblImport").RecordCount & " records"
MsgBox DCount("*", "tblImport") & " records"
```

However if you need or just want to do it with a recordset, use a faster approach for `OpenRecordset`.

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblImport", dbOpenTable, dbReadOnly)
rs.MoveLast
MsgBox rs.RecordCount & " records"
```